# ReactJs and Passport Auth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

m trying to make auth system with react and Passport js

My passport look like this:

```
let passport = require('passport');
let User = require('../models/user');
let localStorage = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user)
    })
});

passport.use('local.signup', new localStorage({
    usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password', passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
    //Check valid
    req.checkBody(req.body.email, 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody(req.body.password, 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min: 4});
    req.checkBody(req.body.name, 'Name is require!').notEmpty();
    let errors = req.validationErrors(); //Get all errors for checkBody

    if(errors){
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error){
            messages.push(error.msg)
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    } 

    User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, function(err, user){
        if(err) return done(err);
        if(user) return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use'});

        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.email= req.body.email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(req.body.password);
        newUser.name = req.body.name;

        newUser.save((err, user) => {
            if(err) return done(err);
            return done(null, user);
        })
    })
}));
```

My route file:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
let router = express.Router();

let User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
    failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true
}), function(req, res,next){
   console.log('Yes signUp');
});

module.exports = router;
```

React file:

```
handleChange = ev => {
        this.setState({[ev.target.name]: ev.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        let user = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/signup', user)
             .then(res=> { console.log(res) })
             .catch(err=> { console.error(err) })           
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container login-container">
                <div className="title-login text-center">Login</div>
                <hr/>
                <div className="login-form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder="Enter your Email.." onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Enter your Name.." onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={this.state.password} placeholder="Enter your password.." onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The error is:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3001/ 404 (Not Found) signup:1 Failed to load
>   http://localhost:3001/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status
>   code 404. index.js:2178 Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

Help!

Comment: you may need to enable cors in nodejs server

Comment: Maybe with Cors?

Comment: I add also 

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

Bust same problem

Comment: can you try this 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") 
        res.send(200);
    else 
        next();
}

Comment: Same Problem

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'); res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); if (req.method === "OPTIONS") res.send(200); else next(); 
});

Comment: make sure that the order of nodejs is 1)app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
2)app.use("---------cors above---------------------")
3) your routes

Comment: The problem is here:

    req.checkBody(req.body.email, 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody(req.body.password, 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min: 4});
    req.checkBody(req.body.name, 'Name is require!').notEmpty();
    let errors = req.validationErrors(); //Get all errors for checkBody

    if(errors){
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error){
            messages.push(error.msg)
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    } 

But all is right